# Built-in alarm, calendar suddenly talking to me. How can I shut them up?

Tags: notifications, calendar, alarm

I use the native Clock app, and my alarm used to just have a normal ringtone. I assume there was some automatic update recently because this morning, in addition to the normal ringtone, there was a robotic voice saying "It is 7:25 AM." Then later I got a notification from the native Calendar app, and in addition to my normal ringtone, the robotic voice announced the text of the notification.

How do I shut this off? It's really annoying and I don't see an option in Settings.

Answer (score 2):

Per a coworker's recommendation, I just went into S-Voice and said "driving mode off". Fixed the issue.